# Play! Framework Historical Data Changes

Tags: jpa, playframework

I have an application I'm building in Play! Framework with a bunch of data that I would like to track changes to.  In a enterprise solution, I would likely use database triggers to copy the changes to a historical table to track those changes.  I am not familiar with a similar paradigm in Play!/JPA, but maybe I'm missing something.  Is there a decent way to do this other than me creating a copy of all of my entities and manually copying the data from the old/unchanged record to the historical, then saving the changes to the original model?

Answer (score 1):

If you data is very critical to keep all the data changes I would stick with the triggers. Because as database doing the updates so there is no possible [clock skew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew) in the cluster running the web app and if a non-JPA client accesses the database then you could keep updates as well.

However, if you are not so obsesive about these kind of concerns than I would suggest you magic `EntityListener`s such as:

- @PrePersist
- @PreUpdate
- @PreRemove
- @PostPersist
- @PostUpdate
- @PostRemove

Here you could find examples of how to use [EntityListener](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/0680__EntityListener.htm),

Answer (score 0):

If you use EclipseLink JPA, you can enable history support.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History

Comment: is it even possible to use EclipseLink for Play 1.2.4?